# Powershell script for pinging servers

Tags: windows, powershell, file, ping, ini

I'd like to write a powershell script for pinging servers. The script would call .ini file which contains a list of servers to be pinged.

Could you please advise how to do this?

Comment: Sure - first import from .ini file ([this](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PsIni/2.0.3) can help). Then process it using loop ([foreach](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/basics-of-powershell-looping-foreach/)) and then use [Test-Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection?view=powershell-7) to ping. If you're stuck at any step and searching the internet doesn't help, feel free to ask. See [ask] for more tips about asking good questions.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just a list of server ip addresses then the following would work.

```
Get-Content "c:\testvalues.ini" | foreach { Test-Connection $_ }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works well in powershell 5 to ping in parallel:

```
$list = get-content list.ini
test-connection $list -AsJob -count 1 | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

If a computer is down, the column under the header "Time(ms)" will be blank, or the ResponseTime property will be $null.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your solution works fine if there are only server names in .ini file.
What if I put other data in the .ini file and I would like to get info only for computer names?
E.g.:

Comment: systemtype=bi
sid=BOZ
loc=NEW
path=K:\BOBJ\Scripts
domain=NA
Computername=NEWBOZ01,NEWBOZ02,NEWBOZ03
sid=BOA
loc=MIC
domai=NA
Computername=MICBOA01,MICBOA02,MICBOA03

Comment: @Kornel if you want to do something like that I would suggest using `.csv` or `.json` format.

Answer (score 0):

I prepared a small PowerShell script which will help to ping the windows/Linux hosts via tcp ping.

In this script I pinged Linux host using TCP port 22 from my windows desktop.

You can modify the port number as per your convenient in the script itself.

For Example:

Linux = Port 22 (SSH TCP)

```
.\paping.exe $line -p 22 -c 1
```

Windows = Port 3389 (RDP TCP)

```
.\paping.exe $line -p 3389 -c 1
```

**Step 1:** Download "**paping**" network utility from the below URL.

https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/paping/paping_1.5.5_x86_windows.zip

**Step 2:** Extract the downloaded zip file in your desktop.

**Step 3:** Create a text file name as "ips.txt" and store in to your desktop under "paping_1.5.5_x86_windows" folder.

**Step 4:** Copy the below script and save into the PowerShell name as "tcpping.ps1"

```
Clear-Host
Clear-Content .\success.log -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Clear-Content .\failure.log -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
foreach($line in Get-Content .\ips.txt) 

{
.\paping.exe $line -p 22 -c 1
if ( $? -eq $True )

{
   $currentTime = Get-Date -Format “MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm K”
    Write-Host $currentTime Node $line is up
    
    "$(Get-Date -DisplayHint datetime) Node $line is up" | Tee-Object -FilePath "success.log" -Append

}

else
{
$currentTime = Get-Date -Format “MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm K”
 Write-Host $currentTime Node $line is down
 "$(Get-Date -DisplayHint datetime) Node $line is down" | Tee-Object -FilePath "failure.log" -Append

 }

}
```

**Step 5:** Right click PowerShell script and Run with PowerShell.

**Step 6:** You can view the tcp ping success and failure results in the same folder log files.

**Step 7:** Below is the sample ping test result script output for your reference

```
07/18/2021 23:27:45 Node 192.168.0.10 is up
07/18/2021 23:27:47 Node 192.168.0.11 is down
```